# Behaviour of liquid in vaccume

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Is it possible for a liquid to exist in a high quality vacuume? For example, a few Torr.

If so what are the methods for doing this?

Comment: What is "quality" of a vacuum? What makes that quality "high"?

Comment: Means good vaccume like outer space.

Comment: Aha, and that "outer space" is "a few" Torr?

Comment: Assume it 0 or few torr.

Comment: Asside: A few Torr is not a particularly good vacuum (only $10^{-3}$ Atm), nuclear and particle physicist use vacuums at or below $10^{-6}$ Atm on a regular basis.

Answer (score 4):

It's absolutely possible to have stable liquids at low pressures. It all depends on the equilibrium phase diagram of the liquid in question.

Looking at the [triple points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point) (a good estimate of the lowest pressure at which the liquid is stable) for a variety of liquids, you can see that [mercury](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/hardware/cal/lvps_info/engineering/elements.pdf) for example (it's in this pdf, I promise) has its triple point at -38 C and ~$10^{-6}$ Torr. In other words, liquid mercury is thermodynamically stable near this pressure and temperature and can thus certainly be stable at a pressure of a few Torr.